# Open a spreadsheet and auto enter a password to a linked spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet set up which has some formulae linked to a protected spreadsheet (Example B), meaning even though my initial spreadsheet (Example A) is unprotected I have to enter the password for the other one each time to update the data - is there any way I can add some VBA to automatically enter the password for ExB when I open the ExA?

I've tried the below as a private sub in ExA but with no joy, it still asks for the password.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="file path", Password:="Password"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have only Sheet protected, not whole Workbook try to use:

```
Sub uncode()

'code to unprotect
Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "password"

'your code, updating data

'code to protect
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect "password"

End Sub
```

Comment: The linked workbook is protected, the workbook I want the VBA in has no protection

Comment: If the entire workbook is protected then you are out of luck. You should look into converting it into a database instead if possible.

Comment: Have You tried    Workbooks.Open Filename:="file path", Password:="pass to open", WriteResPassword:="pass to rewrite" ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to open the 2nd workbook from the first. Try this

1. Open ExB first
2. Open ExA next
3. Close ExB

Try this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Dim wbB As Workbook

    Set wbB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\SomePath\ExB.xlsx", Password:="SomePassword")
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\SomePath\ExA.xlsx", Password:="SomePassword")
    wbB.Close (False)
End Sub
```